# How to set view of programatically created view controller to SKView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, transition, skscene

I am developing a game and would like to have one sprite-kit scene have its own view controller (a conclusion I've reached after much debate), and would like to avoid using storyboard (I can accomplish what I want with storyboard, but would like to learn how to do it without storyboard).

In my main view controller, after clicking a button, I have the following code

```
MyViewController2 *test = [[MyViewController2 alloc] init]; 
test.view = [[SKView alloc] init];
[self presentViewController: test animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, this just transitions a grey screen with nothing on it (did not overwrite "-(id)init" yet). The following code gets called if I overwrite the "-(id)init" method in MyViewController2:

```
-(id)init
{
    NSLog(@"init overwrite works");
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    SKScene2 *scene = [SKScene2 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeFill;
    [skView presentScene:scene];
    return self;
}
```

but it won't display because I get this error:

```
-[UIView presentScene:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I know what this error means (the presentScene can only be executed by skView and can't be executed by UIView), but even though when I create the ViewController and in its init I set views to be only SKView, I still get this error. How can I fix this? Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `view` property is managed by the `UIViewController` and represents the root view. You cannot simply assign your own view at any point.

**Option 1**

If you wish to replace the view property with your own view you can override `UIViewController`'s `loadView` method and assign the view there. It is documented in the class reference for this method:

> The view controller calls this method when its view property is
>   requested but is currently nil. This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view property
>
> ...
>
> You can override this method in order to create your views manually.
>   If you choose to do so, assign the root view of your view hierarchy to
>   the view property

So it will look something like this:

```
- (void)loadView 
{
    self.view = [[SKView alloc] init];
}
```

**Option 2**

You can add your SKView as a subview.

Add a property to your view controller so you can access it when necessary:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKView *skView;
```

Initialize and add it as a subview when the view is loaded:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.skView = [[SKView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.skView];

    SKScene2 *scene = [SKScene2 sceneWithSize:self.skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeFill;
    [self.skView presentScene:scene];
}
```