# How can I obtain an SKScene's size in `didMove(to view: SKView)` when setting scaleMode to resizeFill?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene

I need the SKScene's size to make some initial calculations in my didMove method. When I use the SKSceneScaleMode case of resizeFill to set the scaleMode of my gameScene the self.size values are (0, 0) in the gameScene's didMove method. When I query the size in other methods such as touchesBegan the values are what would be expected (non-zero values that match the size of the scene). This issue only occurs when setting the gameScene.scalemode to resizeFill before presenting the scene. Any other case of SKSceneScaleMode works fine.

Here is the example code

```
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        self.view = SKView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let skView = view as! SKView
        let gameScene = GameScene(size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
        gameScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        skView.presentScene(gameScene)
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print(self.size) // self.size == (0,0)
        // ...calculations using self.size
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            print(self.size) // self.size has expected, non-zero valeus
     }
}
```

I am not using storyboards or sks files. Here is what the appDelegate looks like

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let gameViewController = GameViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = gameViewController
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new view with `self.view = SKView()` in `loadView()`? Are you using a Storyboard?

Comment: I am not using any storyboards. This is how to set a view of a programmatically created view controller to SKView. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31088103/7442289

Comment: The reason your scene size is (0,0) in `didMove` is because you created a view without specifying its size, so SpriteKit resized the scene to match the view. If you created the view with `self.view = SKView(frame:CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)`, the scene's size would be correct in `didMove()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you aren't calling `super.didMove(to:view)`.  Try that first, if that doesn't work, then do:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    super.didMove(to:view)
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        print(self.size)
    }
}
```

What this will do is tell the GCD to run this block shortly after your function ends.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as using GCD works. Calling super did not.